# How do I fill the space in the centre of my circuit in 2.79?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm learning how to make custom tracks for a game called BallisticNG and it requires me to use version 2.79 of Blender specifically due to a neccesary addon not being updated for 2.8.

[image]

In the above image is the basic track I created within the game's track creator and exported as an OBJ for the purpose of adding terrain in Blender. My current goal is trying to fill the center hole along the top most edges of the inner wall. I've tried the Grid Fill option but for somereason it just doesn't want to work with this track.

File Here:
[image]

Comment: Do you need it to be the same mesh? Perhaps share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I've uploaded the file. The meshes themselves were exported OBJ's from the ingame track layout builder in BallisticNG so weren't made in Blender itself. Before I forget to mention, The terrain is required to be seperate from the track walls as the track is merely a guide for building on and requires deletion as it clips into the track layout already present in Unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you could do:

- First clean your mesh a bit, make <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles* to remove the doubles and merge vertices, and untriangulate with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

[image]

- Now as you have merged the vertices you can select the rim with a simple <kbd>Alt</kbd> left click, fill the face with <kbd>F</kbd> and join some vertices so that its more blender friendly. It is still a ngon though, do you need a quad grid?

[image]

Comment: Well damn. I figured it be something so obvious I'd feel stupid afterwards. That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. On that note, what exactly is a Quad Grid? Does that divide that whole area into squares? If so, knowing how to make it a Quad Grid would be of benefit to me.

Comment: Yes I was wondering if you needed a grid made of only quads, here you can see that my big faces are ngons (faces made of more than 4 vertices). But to easily fill these faces with a grid I don't know how to do, with some topology it's very easy: select the rim and press ctrl F > Grid Fill and it works

Comment: Topology? I'm completely new to 3D modelling sorry. I don't understand a lot of terms.

Comment: you should check a tuto about Grid Fill, it allows you to fill a shape with quads, but I don't know if we could use it with your mesh, therefore my solution: just fill the whole shape, then cut a bit from a vertex to another with some J, or with the knife tool

Comment: I tried Grid fill but it doesn't seem to work. It always tells me to select two edge loops despite having the loop selected but if I do select two it tells me closed loops are unsupported. Seems my only option is the solution you put forth

Comment: to make a grid fill you need to select 2 opposite edges and it will fill with a grid of quads, but impossible to use on a such complicated shape, maybe another tool exists for this purpose but I don't think so

Comment: Grid Fill does work. For the sake of it I did select two opposite edges from the track and used Grid Fill and it filled it. I chose one roughly center on the left then one that would be just below centre right if looking top down

Answer (score 0):

Grid fill works when **connected edge loops**, that have **the same** number of vertices, are selected. And it's used i.a. in sculpting organic shapes such as human faces.

Comment: I've tried using Grid Fill but it doesn't seem to want to work with this track. I've uploaded the .blend if you'd like to take a look yourself and perhaps show me what I've done wrong? The track mesh itself wasn't made in Blender but exported as an OBJ via BallisticNG's ingame track layout builder.

Comment: @Katcher: show us the image of what you want to do. Like, should the terrain be a mountain inside?

Comment: Nah nothing complex like that. I'm just going after "flat" land that follows the track and is flush with the top edges of the inner wall. So more like a flush bank of grass/dirt/sand/whatever. Sorry I don't really have an image to provide.

Comment: Just select the rim and hit F which gives you an N-gon fill ver. 2.78 =< allows.